# MSIX: App installation failed with error message

Tags: azure-devops, msix

I created an MSIX package using the steps in this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/azure-dev-ops in my azure devops account.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AppInstaller
    Uri="file://shares/Intranet/Dev/DotnetCore/DotnetCoreInstaller.appinstaller"
    Version="1.0.12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/appinstaller/2017/2">
    <MainPackage
        Name="57d2f575-7f7d-4529-badd-249f9e6e79b8"
        Version="1.0.12.0"
        Publisher="CN=21st Mortgage Corporation, O=21st Mortgage Corporation, L=Knoxville, S=Tennessee, C=US"
        Uri="file://21stmortgage/shares/Intranet/Dev/DotnetCore/DesktopApp.msix" />
    <UpdateSettings>
        <OnLaunch
            HoursBetweenUpdateChecks="0" />
    </UpdateSettings>
</AppInstaller>
```

I also added .appinstaller file as shown in the above article. When I click on the .appinstaller file to install the app on the target machine, I get the below error.

*App installation failed with error message: The package full name returned from the AppxManifest (57d2f575-7f7d-4529-badd-249f9e6e79b8_1.0.12.0_x64__y43p6npyeryve) does not match the name generated from the AppInstaller (57d2f575-7f7d-4529-badd-249f9e6e79b8_1.0.12.0_neutral__y43p6npyeryve). Please ensure that the package attributes specified in the .appinstaller file match the package attributes referenced in file://shares/Intranet/Dev/DotnetCore/DesktopApp.msix. (0x8008020c)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to set the `ProcessorArchitecture` attribute for `MainPackage` property in your .appinstaller file.

If the `ProcessorArchitecture` attribute is not set, its default value `neutral` will be used.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-identity) for more information.

See below set `ProcessorArchitecture` to `x64`, as the full name returned from the AppxManifest is (...._1.0.12.0_**x64**__...)

```
<MainPackage
        Name="57d2f575-7f7d-4529-badd-249f9e6e79b8"
        Version="1.0.12.0"
        Publisher="CN=21st Mortgage Corporation, O=21st Mortgage Corporation, L=Knoxville, S=Tennessee, C=US"
        Uri="file://21stmortgage/shares/Intranet/Dev/DotnetCore/DesktopApp.msix" 
        ProcessorArchitecture="x64"/>
```